# How to send large numbers via UDP in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, udp

I would like to know if I can receive integers larger than 127 (fscanf) or 255 (fread) in MATLAB.

I am sending them via UDP datagram from C++ based application and how to do it. I can send them as char, but they are coded as utf16 in visual studio, and utf8 in matlab, so there is overload after 127 as well.

Comment: Send binary data (not text), and use `typecast`. Example: `echoudp('on',4012);u = udp('127.0.0.1',4012);fopen(u);a=uint32(12345678);A=typecast(a,'uint8');fwrite(u,A);B=fread(u,4,'uint8');B=uint8(B');b=typecast(B,'uint32');fclose(u);echoudp('off');display(b)`

Comment: What do you need that for? Matlab has no native support for big number or arbitrary precision numbers AON AFAIK. You could find a library to work with these numbers, but then you should read its documentation. But if data is only passing by, I'm again unsure how the situation should be handled.